# Android NDK: Undefined reference error

Tags: android, android-ndk, irrlicht

When I am compiling irrlicht project it showing me so many undefined reference error. I guess its looking for egl.h which comes with android ndk package.

Here is error logs :

```
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libirrlichttest.so
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::handleInput(android_app*, AInputEvent*):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:274: error: undefined reference to 'AInputEvent_getType'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::handleInput(android_app*, AInputEvent*):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:277: error: undefined reference to 'AMotionEvent_getPointerCount'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::handleInput(android_app*, AInputEvent*):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:278: error: undefined reference to 'AMotionEvent_getAction'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::handleInput(android_app*, AInputEvent*):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:313: error: undefined reference to 'AMotionEvent_getX'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::handleInput(android_app*, AInputEvent*):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:314: error: undefined reference to 'AMotionEvent_getY'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::closeDevice():jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:171: error: undefined reference to 'ANativeActivity_finish'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::run():jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:110: error: undefined reference to 'ALooper_pollAll'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::CIrrDeviceAndroid(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:55: error: undefined reference to 'ASensorManager_getInstance'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::CIrrDeviceAndroid(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:56: error: undefined reference to 'ASensorManager_createEventQueue'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::CIrrDeviceAndroid(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:69: error: undefined reference to 'ALooper_pollAll'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::CIrrDeviceAndroid(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:55: error: undefined reference to 'ASensorManager_getInstance'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::CIrrDeviceAndroid(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:56: error: undefined reference to 'ASensorManager_createEventQueue'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::CIrrDeviceAndroid(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:69: error: undefined reference to 'ALooper_pollAll'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::handleAndroidCommand(android_app*, int):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:215: error: undefined reference to 'ANativeWindow_getWidth'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CIrrDeviceAndroid.o): in function irr::CIrrDeviceAndroid::handleAndroidCommand(android_app*, int):jni/Android/CIrrDeviceAndroid.cpp:216: error: undefined reference to 'ANativeWindow_getHeight'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetReader.o): in function .LTHUNK10:jni/Android/CAndroidAssetReader.cpp:57: error: undefined reference to 'AAsset_getLength'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetReader.o): in function .LTHUNK11:jni/Android/CAndroidAssetReader.cpp:62: error: undefined reference to 'AAsset_getLength'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetReader.o): in function .LTHUNK11:jni/Android/CAndroidAssetReader.cpp:62: error: undefined reference to 'AAsset_getRemainingLength'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetReader.o): in function .LTHUNK9:jni/Android/CAndroidAssetReader.cpp:50: error: undefined reference to 'AAsset_seek'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetReader.o): in function .LTHUNK8:jni/Android/CAndroidAssetReader.cpp:45: error: undefined reference to 'AAsset_read'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetReader.o): in function .LTHUNK5:jni/Android/CAndroidAssetReader.cpp:40: error: undefined reference to 'AAsset_close'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetReader.o): in function irr::io::CAndroidAssetReader::~CAndroidAssetReader():jni/Android/CAndroidAssetReader.cpp:40: error: undefined reference to 'AAsset_close'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetReader.o): in function irr::io::CAndroidAssetReader::CAndroidAssetReader(irr::core::string<char, irr::core::irrAllocator<char> > const&):jni/Android/CAndroidAssetReader.cpp:32: error: undefined reference to 'AAssetManager_open'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetReader.o): in function irr::io::CAndroidAssetReader::CAndroidAssetReader(irr::core::string<char, irr::core::irrAllocator<char> > const&):jni/Android/CAndroidAssetReader.cpp:32: error: undefined reference to 'AAssetManager_open'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetFileArchive.o): in function irr::io::CAndroidAssetFileArchive::addDirectory(irr::core::string<char, irr::core::irrAllocator<char> > const&):jni/Android/CAndroidAssetFileArchive.cpp:87: error: undefined reference to 'AAssetManager_openDir'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CAndroidAssetFileArchive.o): in function irr::io::CAndroidAssetFileArchive::addDirectory(irr::core::string<char, irr::core::irrAllocator<char> > const&):jni/Android/CAndroidAssetFileArchive.cpp:92: error: undefined reference to 'AAssetDir_getNextFileName'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::swapBuffers():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:348: error: undefined reference to 'eglSwapBuffers'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::destroyContext():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:323: error: undefined reference to 'eglMakeCurrent'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::destroyContext():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:324: error: undefined reference to 'eglDestroyContext'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::destroySurface():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:271: error: undefined reference to 'eglMakeCurrent'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::destroySurface():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:273: error: undefined reference to 'eglDestroySurface'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::terminate():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:85: error: undefined reference to 'eglMakeCurrent'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::terminate():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:87: error: undefined reference to 'eglTerminate'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::generateSurface():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:157: error: undefined reference to 'eglChooseConfig'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::generateSurface():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:240: error: undefined reference to 'eglGetConfigAttrib'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::generateSurface():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:242: error: undefined reference to 'ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::generateSurface():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:246: error: undefined reference to 'eglCreateWindowSurface'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::generateSurface():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:249: error: undefined reference to 'eglCreateWindowSurface'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::generateSurface():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:256: error: undefined reference to 'eglBindAPI'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::generateSurface():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:260: error: undefined reference to 'eglSwapInterval'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::testEGLError():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:354: error: undefined reference to 'eglGetError'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::activateContext(irr::video::SExposedVideoData const&):jni/CEGLManager.cpp:331: error: undefined reference to 'eglMakeCurrent'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::generateContext():jni/CEGLManager.cpp:307: error: undefined reference to 'eglCreateContext'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::initialize(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&, irr::video::SExposedVideoData const&):jni/CEGLManager.cpp:51: error: undefined reference to 'eglGetDisplay'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(CEGLManager.o): in function irr::video::CEGLManager::initialize(irr::SIrrlichtCreationParameters const&, irr::video::SExposedVideoData const&):jni/CEGLManager.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'eglInitialize'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(COGLES2Driver.o): in function irr::video::COGLES2Driver::testEGLError():jni/COGLES2Driver.cpp:1633: error: undefined reference to 'eglGetError'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(COGLESExtensionHandler.o): in function irr::video::COGLES1ExtensionHandler::initExtensions(irr::video::COGLES1Driver*, bool):jni/COGLESExtensionHandler.cpp:246: error: undefined reference to 'eglGetProcAddress'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(COGLESExtensionHandler.o): in function irr::video::COGLES1ExtensionHandler::initExtensions(irr::video::COGLES1Driver*, bool):jni/COGLESExtensionHandler.cpp:247: error: undefined reference to 'eglGetProcAddress'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(COGLESExtensionHandler.o): in function irr::video::COGLES1ExtensionHandler::initExtensions(irr::video::COGLES1Driver*, bool):jni/COGLESExtensionHandler.cpp:248: error: undefined reference to 'eglGetProcAddress'
D:/Work/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/libirrlicht.a(COGLESExtensionHandler.o): in function irr::video::COGLES1ExtensionHandler::initExtensions(irr::video::COGLES1Driver*, bool):jni/COGLESExtensionHandler.cpp:249: error: undefined reference to 'eglGetProcAddress'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libirrlichttest.so] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

And here is my android.mk(Removing some of cpp files just to take screenshot )

> [image]

And here is my application.mk

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
APP_MODULE := irrlicht
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try with LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := -landroid, instead of android_native_app_glue. I don't even think there is a library called that.

Comment: @user2359247 same result..

Comment: OK, I am wrong, there is a static library called android_native_app_glue. Try with this then: LOCAL_LDLIBS := -landroid
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

Comment: @user2359247 yaa android_native_app_glue is there, tried again still same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly add NDK include directory to your CFLAGS. If the project fails to compile without it, your configuration is wrong.

Your Android.mk misses

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lEGL
```

and probably some more ndk libs

Comment: Hey @alex finally compile my lib files successfully, but my app automatically close without giving me any error while calling CreateDevice, do you have any idea about it.

Comment: I don't know what `CreateDevice()` is, but it's strange that `logcat` is empty.